# How to color odd columns of an empty css grid?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

Let's say I have a simple html CSS script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(27, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, minmax(0, 1fr));
  height: 50rem;
  width: 50rem;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid">
  <!-- Your grid items will go here, but for this example, we're leaving them empty -->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I want the odd columns of the grid meaning 1,3,5,etc.. to be the color gray.

Notice that I don't have any elements in the grid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a gradient coloration:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(27, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, minmax(0, 1fr));
  height: 50rem;
  width: 50rem;
  
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,#ccc 50%,#0000 0) 0/calc(200%/27);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <!-- Your grid items will go here, but for this example, we're leaving them empty -->
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

To color odd columns of an empty CSS grid, you can use the :nth-child pseudo-class to target the grid items within the odd columns.
for Example:
In CSS,

```
.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue; /* Set your desired background color */
}
```

Comment: There are no grid items to select. I suggest you re-read the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).